# Transform value into missing by position

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, missing-data

In a dataset I need to transform into missing the values in the column `value`, in two cases:

1. If grouping by type, the line is the last line
2. If grouping by type, the next value line is a missing value

This solves the first part:

```
toy %>% 
  group_by(type) %>%
  mutate(value = ifelse(row_number()==max(row_number()),NA,value))
```

How do I go about tackling the second one? Thanks in advance

```
toy <- data_frame(type=c(rep("A",4),rep("B",4)),year=rep(c(1:4),2),value=c(1,1,NA,1,1,1,1,1))

# A tibble: 8 x 3
  type   year value
  <chr> <int> <dbl>
1 A         1     1
2 A         2     1
3 A         3    NA
4 A         4     1
5 B         1     1
6 B         2     1
7 B         3     1
8 B         4     1


expected <- data_frame(type=c(rep("A",4),rep("B",4)),year=rep(c(1:4),2),value=c(1,NA,NA,NA,1,1,1,NA))

  type   year value
  <chr> <int> <dbl>
1 A         1     1
2 A         2    NA
3 A         3    NA
4 A         4    NA
5 B         1     1
6 B         2     1
7 B         3     1
8 B         4    NA
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `lead` you can combine both the conditions :

```
library(dplyr)

toy %>%
  group_by(type) %>%
  mutate(value = replace(value, is.na(lead(value)), NA)) %>%
  ungroup

#  type   year value
#  <chr> <int> <dbl>
#1 A         1     1
#2 A         2    NA
#3 A         3    NA
#4 A         4    NA
#5 B         1     1
#6 B         2     1
#7 B         3     1
#8 B         4    NA
```

`lead` will give the next value and if it is `NA` we change the current value to `NA`. Also `lead` returns last value as `NA` by default hence the first condition (`If grouping by type, the line is the last line`) is automatically satisfied.

---

The same can be solved with `data.table` as :

```
library(data.table)

setDT(toy)[,value := replace(value, is.na(shift(value, type = 'lead')),NA), type]
```